# Search Query in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel 5.6,

How can I convert below query in laravel **query builder or Eloquent**?

```
SELECT * FROM books 
WHERE book_title LIKE '%something%' 
OR book_author LIKE '%something%'
OR *book_description LIKE '%something%'
```

I searched a lot in google but I was not able to find any solution to much my problem.

Comment: Your sql is almost literally covered in the docs... https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Thanks pradeep for editing!

Comment: I saw the provided link, it is only for one condition or one AND condition and one OR!

Comment: Scroll 10 lines lower and you pretty much get the answer Marcin posted.

Comment: Okay thanks for useful hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eloquent Version:

```
Books::where('book_title ','LIKE','%'.$something.'%')
       ->orWhere('book_author ','LIKE','%'.$something.'%')
       ->orWhere('book_description ','LIKE','%'.$something.'%')->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

Using **query builder** it would look like this:

```
DB::table('books')
        ->where('book_title', 'like', '%'.$variable.'%')
        ->orWhere('book_author', 'like', '%'.$variable.'%')
        ->orWhere('book_description', 'like', '%'.$variable.'%')
        ->get();
```

By the way next time just look into the docs:
[Laravel Docs - Query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and hint, noted!